# PyQt Signals and Slots: "new style" emit?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qt-signals

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to correctly use threads and signals with `PyQt5` and `Python3`, but somehow don't manage to understand how this all works. I found a sample code here and am now trying to make it work in `PyQt5`.

Here is the gui file `ui.py`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_Win(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(416, 292)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Win()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the main script `test_slotting.py`:

```
from ui import Ui_Win
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import time

class GenericThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def __del__(self):
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        #Do all your heavy processing here
        #I'll just wait for 2 seconds
        time.sleep(2)
        self.emit(QtCore.pyqtSignal('itemSelectionChanged()'))
        return


class MainUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Win()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.List1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.ui.List2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.ui.List1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.ui.List2)

        self.ui.centralWidget.setLayout(hbox)

        self.ui.List1.addItems(['alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon'])
        self.ui.List2.addItems(['Item1','Item2'])

        self.ui.List1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.start_heavy_processing_thread)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start_heavy_processing_thread(self):
        genericThread = GenericThread(self)
        # self.connect(genericThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.fill_List2 )
        genericThread.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.fill_List2)
        genericThread.start()

    def fill_List2(self):
        self.ui.List2.clear()
        list1SelectedItem = str(self.ui.List1.currentItem().text())
        self.ui.List2.addItem(list1SelectedItem)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainUI()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

From the initial code example, I had to change "old style"

```
self.connect(genericThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.fill_List2 )
```

to "new style"

```
self.ui.List1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.start_heavy_processing_thread)
```

However, now I'm getting the following `AttributeError: 'GenericThread' object has no attribute 'itemSelectionChanged'`. I guess this line from `test_slotting.py` is still "old style":

```
self.emit(QtCore.pyqtSignal('itemSelectionChanged()'))
```

But what would be the new style version of it? Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite expected. Your `GenericThread` has no signal named `itemSelectionChanged()` hence you cannot connect a non-existing signal to a slot. This signal belongs to your `QListWidget` and not to your `GenericThread`.

I would suggest to read more on how `QThread` works before you decide to create your custom one. Especially if that thread of yours works with slots and signals where you actually do the "heavy processing", you will get screwed due to the nature of `QThread` - only what's inside `run()` actually runs inside a separate thread. The rest (slots, signals, class members etc.) belong to the thread where you have spawned your own `QThread` from - in your case this is the main thread.

I have uploaded an example of working with PyQt and threads [here](https://gitlab.com/aleksandaratanasov/pyqt_threaded_ui/blob/master/threaded_ui.py) where you can see how things are usually done. I am also using the new style there.

---

**Short explanation about the new style:**

Let's say you have a `QWidget`-derived class with a `QPushButton` in it called `button` and a slot `do_work()` that you want to trigger whenever the button is clicked. In order to establish this connection you will have to do the following:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.do_work)
      |        |              |    |
      |        |              |    |
      |   signal of emitter   |  slot of receiver
      |                       |
  signal emitter            signal receiver
```

In this case `self` is the receiver hence we use `self.do_work` to say that the slot `do_work` belongs to `self` and it's where the signal `clicked`, emitted by `button`, has to land.

PS: I have noticed that you try to use decorators but do that only partially. If you want to use these (I strongly recommend to do that), you need to add a slot decorator to your `fill_List2()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. Stupid error by using `itemSelectionChanged()` on `GenericThread` instead of the `QListWidget`, sry for that. I still need to read up quite a bit on `QThread`, thx for the tip. Thx also for the code example, will also hv to check that out in more detail. I managed to patch sth together and make my example run. However there are still some bits that I don't really understand (comments in code, feel free to help if you like :) ). Again, thx for your help!

Comment: oh and P.S.: the illustration is really super helpful!

Comment: Glad I can help. As I wrote in my answer - do take a look at the my git repository where I use threads. It should given you enough to get a better grip of all this.

Answer (score 0):

**The updated code**

**ui.py:**

```
 from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


    class Ui_Win(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(416, 292)
            self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

            self.List1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
            self.List2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

            self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.hbox.addStretch(1)
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.List1)
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.List2)

            self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.hbox)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_Win()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test_slotting.py:**

```
from ui import Ui_Win
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject

class Trigger(QObject):  # --> or QtCore.QThread? What's the difference?
    trigger = pyqtSignal()

    def connect_emit(self, pressed_item, list_to_update):
        self.pressed_item = pressed_item  # --> this kind of looks ugly to me... hmmm...
        self.list_to_update = list_to_update  # --> this kind of looks ugly to me... hmmm...

        self.trigger.connect(self.run)
        self.trigger.emit()

    def run(self):
        self.list_to_update.clear()
        self.list_to_update.addItem(self.pressed_item)


class MainUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Win()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.List1.addItems(['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon'])
        self.ui.List2.addItems(['Item1', 'Item2'])

        self.ui.List1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.start_heavy_processing_thread)

    @pyqtSlot()  # --> what does this actually do? code also works without it...
    def start_heavy_processing_thread(self):
        genericThread = Trigger()
        myitem = [str(x.text()) for x in self.ui.List1.selectedItems()][0]
        mylist = self.ui.List2
        genericThread.connect_emit(myitem, mylist)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainUI()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```